# How to make UI look Pixel Perfect in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, pixel

I am working on an pixel game and now I want to add the UI, and it needs to work at different scales and so on. That's why I used the Unity UI System. However, now UI doesn't look pixel-perfect, the pixels are distorted.

(I am using a script that scales the camera to make the UI look good in every resolution. The script is not mine though)

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Rendering;
    
namespace GGEZ
{    
    [
     ExecuteInEditMode,                                       // Run this script in edit mode so the preview window looks good
     RequireComponent (typeof(Camera)),                       // Only add this component if there is a camera
     HelpURL ("http://ggez.org/posts/perfect-pixel-camera/"), // Website opened by clicking the book icon on the component
     DisallowMultipleComponent,                               // Only one of these per GameObject
     AddComponentMenu ("GGEZ/Camera/Perfect Pixel Camera")    // Insert into the "Add Component..." menu
    ]
    public class PerfectPixelCamera : MonoBehaviour
    {
    
    // Set this value to the same value as Pixels Per Unit when importing sprites
    [
        Tooltip ("The number of texture pixels that fit in 1.0 world units. Common values are 8, 16, 32 and 64. If you're making a tile-based game, this is your tile size."),
        Range (1, 64)
    ]
    public int TexturePixelsPerWorldUnit = 16;
    
    // Reference to the camera on this same GameObject. Found
    // by the OnEnable function.
    private Camera cameraComponent;
    
    // Set to a value that compensates for the half-pixel offset when rendering
    // with Direct3D. This is automatically handled by Unity 5.5 and later.
    // If that's the case, it is declared as a constant 0 which the compiler
    // can use to optimize calculations in LateUpdate.
    // See: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UpgradeGuide55.html
    #if UNITY_5_5_OR_NEWER
    private const float halfPixelOffsetIfNeededForD3D = 0f;
    #else
    private float halfPixelOffsetIfNeededForD3D;
    #endif
    
    // Objects that you want to be perfectly aligned should have X and Y
    // coordinates that are integer multiples of this value. It is always
    // safe to align to 1.0 / TexturePixelsPerWorldUnit, but this value can
    // be smaller if the camera is zoomed and will make movement more smooth.
    public float SnapSizeWorldUnits { get; private set; }
    
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // OnEnable - Called by Unity when the component is created or enabled
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void OnEnable ()
        {
    
        // Grab a reference to the camera
        this.cameraComponent = (Camera)this.GetComponent (typeof(Camera));
    
    #if !UNITY_5_5_OR_NEWER
    
        // Detect whether we are using Direct3D, because D3D rendering has a
        // half-pixel offset from OpenGL rendering.
        bool isD3D =
                SystemInfo.graphicsDeviceType == GraphicsDeviceType.Direct3D9
                || SystemInfo.graphicsDeviceType == GraphicsDeviceType.Direct3D11
                || SystemInfo.graphicsDeviceType == GraphicsDeviceType.Direct3D12;
    
        // 0.4975f and not 0.5f is used because 0.5f is able to be represented
        // as a perfect IEEE float. This means that when added to other
        // floats that are imperfect, the results can sometimes be rounded
        // the wrong way. It can be tricky to reproduce so this isn't part
        // of the main demo.
        this.halfPixelOffsetIfNeededForD3D = isD3D ? 0.4975f : 0f;
    
    #endif
    
        // Run the LateUpdate immediately so that the projection gets set up
        this.LateUpdate ();
    
        }
    
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // OnDisable - Called by Unity when the component is disabled or destroyed
    // This function cleans up after the PerfectPixelCamera so that the
    // projection matrix isn't left in an altered state by this component.
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void OnDisable ()
    { 
        if (this.cameraComponent == null)
            {
            return;
            }
        this.cameraComponent.ResetProjectionMatrix ();
        this.cameraComponent = null;
    
        }
    
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // LateUpdate - Called by Unity after all other functions have run Update.
    // If you have other scripts that use LateUpdate, you might want to use
    // the Script Execution Order project setting to make this script run last.
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void LateUpdate ()
        {
    
        // Get a local reference
        Camera camera = this.cameraComponent;
    
        // Make sure the camera is in 2D mode
        camera.transparencySortMode = TransparencySortMode.Orthographic;
        camera.orthographic = true;
        camera.transform.rotation = Quaternion.identity;
        camera.orthographicSize = Mathf.Max (camera.orthographicSize, 0.00001f);
    
        // This is the code that computes the parameters needed to perfectly map
        // world-space pixels to screen-space pixels.
        var pixelRect = camera.pixelRect;
        float texturePixelsPerWorldUnit = this.TexturePixelsPerWorldUnit;
        float zoomFactor = Mathf.Max (1f, Mathf.Ceil ((1f * pixelRect.height) / (camera.orthographicSize * 2f * texturePixelsPerWorldUnit)));
        float halfWidth  = (1f * pixelRect.width)  / (zoomFactor * 2f * texturePixelsPerWorldUnit);
        float halfHeight = (1f * pixelRect.height) / (zoomFactor * 2f * texturePixelsPerWorldUnit);
        float snapSizeWorldUnits = 1f / (zoomFactor * texturePixelsPerWorldUnit);
        float halfPixelOffsetInWorldUnits = halfPixelOffsetIfNeededForD3D * snapSizeWorldUnits;
        float pixelPerfectXOffset = halfPixelOffsetInWorldUnits - Mathf.Repeat (snapSizeWorldUnits + Mathf.Repeat (camera.transform.position.x, snapSizeWorldUnits), snapSizeWorldUnits);
        float pixelPerfectYOffset = halfPixelOffsetInWorldUnits - Mathf.Repeat (snapSizeWorldUnits + Mathf.Repeat (camera.transform.position.y, snapSizeWorldUnits), snapSizeWorldUnits);
    
        // Save the snap size so other scripts can use it
        this.SnapSizeWorldUnits = snapSizeWorldUnits;
    
        // Build a manual projection matrix that fixes the camera!
        camera.projectionMatrix = Matrix4x4.Ortho (
                -halfWidth + pixelPerfectXOffset,
                 halfWidth + pixelPerfectXOffset,
                -halfHeight + pixelPerfectYOffset,
                 halfHeight + pixelPerfectYOffset,
                camera.nearClipPlane,
                camera.farClipPlane
                );
    
        }
    }
}
```

[Pixel Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjv1q.png)
[Inspector of Canvas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVQWX.png)

So, how can I make the UI Pixel Perfect?

Comment: That script seems very old, I don't think you need it in modern Unity. If your UI elements get scaled in a way you don't want, you can use the 9-slice feature in the sprite editor, this will scale elements for different screens without distorting them.

Answer (score 1):

Just set the `PixelPerfect` property to `true` on your canvas.
Unity automatically takes care of what you're trying to do (although it's always nice to have something custom built so, you have more control over it)

Comment: I allready did this and it isnt working ;/ any other ideas?

Comment: Try putting the canvas as world space canvas